# Constant AJAX polling eventually locks Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP web app that uses jquery/AJAX to poll for database info.

Basically I have a setInterval to 5000ms, that does a $.post to a PHP page, that receives an often large sum of data (about 3.5kb to 10kb). I'm finding after a few hours, the web browser slows down to a halt.

All of the data loads into one div (a table). On each request I .empty() the table and append the new table. What can I do to prevent this from lagging the browser?

Some code if it helps:

```
function getData(val ){
    $.post('php/data.php', {
        func: 'getdata', val : val
    }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#results').empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                if (i == "something") {
                    $('#results').append(data.someStuff).......
                }
            });
        }
    }, "json");
}

// On immediate page load

getData(val);

var getData_interval = setInterval(getData.bind(this, val),5000);
```

Comment: Have you set `async: false`? If so, don't.

Comment: Please include your javascript code

Comment: what if you use window.location instead of ajax

Comment: are you sure it takes the db server less than 5 seconds to retrieve the data and send back to you? because you might be executing the ajaxes one over another and then after several hours thosands of them return one after another and freeze your browser

Comment: Fortunately for me the data doesn't even travel the through the net. It is a Windows Server PC and the user only accesses the web app from that PC, so retrieving data is next to instant. There is no backlog. I am not using async : false

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Does this issue occur in all browsers?

Comment: The client only uses Firefox, so only Firefox.

Comment: Do you really need to replace everything? And you should use a timeout like you mentioned in your original question instead of an interval. Just set the timeout in the success function of your ajax call.

Comment: When you look at your browser's developer tools -> Network what do the requests and responses say? Also - it will be highly recommended to simply use setTimeout when the ajax finishes instead of `setInterval`

Comment: it doesnt matter how far it travels, if you have lots of clients, and the db server does other operations too, it might take it on average >5s to process a request. benchmark the speeds on heavy load to make sure.

Comment: I think you're also misusing `.bind`, it should be `getData.bind(window,val)`.

Comment: There's some obvious errors here - `.bind` will not bind the `val` parameter (it should be `.bind(null, val)`, and the `$.each` callback has a signature of `index, val` which seems like maybe not what you're doing.

Comment: Oh also you're missing the `function` keyword - `function getVal(val)` you're probably just getting syntax errors

Comment: Sorry guys I just typed up the code as an example. I have no syntax errors and everything is working perfectly other than the locking up after a long period of polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues can come up when using setInterval instead of a recursive setTimeout. SetInterval will run regardless of weather or not the callback function was successfully executed which means over time you could potentially end up with a hung browser.

Try changing this:

```
getData(val ){
    $.post('php/data.php', {
        func: 'getdata', val : val
    }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#results').empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                if (i == "something") {
                    $('#results').append(data.someStuff).......
                }
            });
        }
    }, "json");
}


var getData_interval = setInterval(getData.bind(val),5000);
```

to this:

```
var myIntervalTime = null;

function getData(val ){
    $.post('php/data.php', {
        func: 'getdata', val : val
    }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#results').empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                if (i == "something") {
                    $('#results').append(data.someStuff).......
                }
            });
        }

        getData_interval();
    }, "json");
}


function getData_interval() {
    myIntervalTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        getData.bind(val);
    }, 5000);
}

function clearGetData_interval() {
   window.clearTimeout(myIntervalTimer);
}

function resetGetData_interval() {
    clearGetData_interval();
    getData_interval();
}
```

This will ensure that your ajax calls only run 5 seconds after the last one completed.

Also, read up on how javascript timers work: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Thanks, I was using setInterval because I can clear the interval when I do something like re-sorting the table or expanding rows. This is helpful because I use jquery animations to do some sorting/hiding, and if I get a new update in the middle of that it will glitch a bit. Any similar way to restart the setTimeout when I do some jquery animations?

Comment: Now I have a slight problem. I like that it will not update again unless it was first successful, but the case may be that the user disconnects their PC from the database and the page remains open. The pages will no longer poll for data because it failed to retrieve data. The result is the page has to be refreshed. Not the end of the world but I guess to remedy, I do in fact need a setInterval in the case of AJAX failing ?

Comment: And maybe I'll just go back to setInterval. It seems to work 100x better than setTimeout. Even though I'm clearing my timeOuts it is still having severe effects on my animations, whereas clearing intervals did not.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted any other code, I will try to help with what I see.
Instead of using `setInterval` at a fixed 5s interval, which is not dependent on the rest of the calls, I would recommend using `setTimeout` every time that the `$.post` method actually is successful.
Using fixed interval will have unexpected results since you can never know the length of the response (what happens if the connection is down for example?)

```
function getData(val ){
    $.post('php/data.php', {
        func: 'getdata', val : val
    }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#results').empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                if (i == "something") {
                    $('#results').append(data.someStuff).......
                }
            });
         //this will only perform the next ajax call on success
         setTimeout(function() {getData(val)},5000);
        }
    }, "json");
}

// On immediate page load

getData(val);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also note the missing `function` keyword

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMauer, I actually just noticed it myself and simply changed it to `getData(val)`.

Comment: Oh and added the `function` as well per your comment :)

Comment: That's what I would do. And you can probably do without the `val` variable going around in circles as well.